# Adding "fixed position" to my sidebar is positioning elements incorrectly, how can this be fixed?

Tags: css, css-position, sidebar

On my blog page, I recently added

```
#sidebar{ position: fixed;}
```

which then causes (1) my facebook icon to move up where the "subscribe" text is and (2) it makes the "sidebar width change as seen in the second photo and (3) creates an odd margin on the right side. I want the sidebar to look as though it did before adding position fixed.

```
#sidebar { 
position: fixed; 
font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Regular","Helvetica Neue Regular","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif; font-weight:700;  
text-align:center;  
margin-bottom:60px;  
background:#F8F9FC;  
border:2px solid #E2E7F5;  
padding:30px;}


<form action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=Blog-JeffreyDowellPhotography', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true"><p>Subscribe via Email:</p><p><input type="text" style="width:140px" name="email"/></p><input type="hidden" value="Blog-JeffreyDowellPhotography" name="uri"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" style=" margin-bottom: 40px;"/></form>


<p style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom:37px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; border-bottom: 2px solid #E2E7F5; border-top: 2px solid #E2E7F5;" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Blog-JeffreyDowellPhotography" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml"><img src="//feedburner.google.com/fb/images/pub/feed-icon16x16.png" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle;border:0"/></a>&nbsp;<a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Blog-JeffreyDowellPhotography" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml">Subscribe via RSS</a></p>




<!-- Facebook Badge START -->
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/JeffreyDowellPhotography" target="_TOP" title="Jeffrey Dowell Photography">
  <img src="https://badge.facebook.com/badge/696174530397916.3512.386387771.png" style="border: 0px;" />
</a>
<!-- Facebook Badge END -->
```

- List item

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `inline-block` style on your "Subscribe" section.

Changing that to `display: block` fixes the problem for me.

See: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/cjLim